# I am not seen " enable eclipse plugin" in lotus designer 9.0.1

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

I am using lotus designer 9.0.1 social edition, i try to enable eclipse plugin but i am not seen that option in File->Preference->lotus designer, and i am also not seen Install ans update option.

NOTE:- my main requirement is to install xpages extension Library in lotus designer 9.0.1 social edition

Comment: You don't need to install Extlib in DDE 9 as is already installed

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is the option you are looking for.  This will enable the File | Application | Install menu option.

[image]

Comment: Santhosh, if this answer fixed your problem then please accept the answer by pressing the large check mark to the left of the answer.

Comment: You probably tried this but did you restart Designer?  The menu options are under File then Application then you will see a section with two choices "Install..." and "Application Management".

Comment: The problem may be the need to get to the preferences from Designer specifically. If you open preferences from Notes, you'll get the same overall Eclipse-style dialog, but it won't contain the Designer-related sections.